# Printing a dict in python3 when python2 statement no longer works

Tags: python-3.x

I had the following print statement in my python2 program (after '-' sign) and replaced it with some more elaborate python3 code (after '+' sign). Is there a better i.e. more elegant way to do this?

```
-                print("%(txn_processed)8d %(txn_skip)5d %(txn_ctr)5d")%accounts[account]
+                acc_ctrs = accounts[account]
+                processed = accounts[account]['txn_processed']
+                skipped = accounts[account]['txn_skip']
+                ctr = accounts[account]['txn_ctr']
+                print('%8d %5d %5d'%(processed, skipped, ctr))
```

The dictionary accounts has one entry per account with 3 counters in a sub dictionary. So I process the accounts in a `for account in accounts:` loop and separate the 3 counters into processed, skipped and sum. This is what the output looks like (specifically the last 2 lines):

```
           Output to ofx (GnuCash version)
TRANSACTIONS: 248
IN:           2018-008-transactions-30-12-to-26-09.csv
OUT:          2018-008-transactions-30-12-to-26-09.ofx
    accountnumber     processed  skip   sum
    NL89RABO0000000000      231     0   231
    NL71RABO1111111111        1    16    17
```

My knowledge of python3 is limited. Hope you guys can help me out.

P.S. the python2 line returned an error message about NoneType and Dict.

Kind regards, Guus.

Comment: Could you please post an example of an input/output? The dictionary and how it should be printed

Comment: Thanks, that helped me clarify my question. +1 and updated the question. Got an answer due to that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` is a function in python 3, but you have confusing parentheses:

Python 2 interpretation is as follows:

```
print ("%(txn_processed)8d %(txn_skip)5d %(txn_ctr)5d") % accounts[account]
#     ^----------------------- argument to print ---------------------------------------^
```

In fact, these parens around a string were entirely unnecessary in python 2.

Python 3 interpretation is to treat parentheses as arguments, as any regular function/method:

```py
print ("%(txn_processed)8d %(txn_skip)5d %(txn_ctr)5d") % accounts[account]
#     ^------------- argument to print --------------^
```

And `print` returns `None`, and you are trying to call `__rem__` on it. That's why you have an error.

All you need to do to fix it for Python 3 is to wrap everything in parentheses instead of just the string you'll be formatting:

```py
print("%(txn_processed)8d %(txn_skip)5d %(txn_ctr)5d" % accounts[account])
#     ^------------- argument to print ---------------------------------^
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly what I was looking for! +1 and set as solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
acc_ctrs = accounts[account]
print('%8d %5d %5d'%(
                     acc_ctrs['txn_processed'],
                     acc_ctrs['txn_skipped'],
                     acc_ctrs['txn_ctr']
     ))
```

Comment: This actually makes sense and provides an alternative to the solution by Oleg. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To print dict in elegant way, use this:

```
import pprint

pprint.pprint(dict)
```

You'll get the output in readable way.